# Json file read failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I browse to http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/ajax-tree-plain.json

I get the following displayed in my browser:

```
[
{"title": "simple node (no explicit id, so a default key is generated)" },
{"key": "2", "title": "item1 with key and tooltip", "tooltip": "Look, a tool tip!" },
{"key": "3", "title": "<span>item2 with <b>html</b> inside a span tag</span>" },
{"key": "4", "title": "node 4" },
{"key": "5", "title": "using href", "href": "http://www.wwWendt.de/" },
{"key": "6", "title": "node with some extra classes (will be added to the generated markup)", "extraClasses": "my-extra-class" },
{"key": "10", "title": "Folder 1", "folder": true, "children": [
    {"key": "10_1", "title": "Sub-item 1.1", "children": [
        {"key": "10_1_1", "title": "Sub-item 1.1.1"},
        {"key": "10_1_2", "title": "Sub-item 1.1.2"}
    ]},
    {"key": "10_2", "title": "Sub-item 1.2", "children": [
        {"key": "10_2_1", "title": "Sub-item 1.2.1"},
        {"key": "10_2_2", "title": "Sub-item 1.2.2"}
    ]}
]},
{"key": "20", "title": "Simple node with active children (expand)", "expanded": true, "children": [
    {"key": "20_1", "title": "Sub-item 2.1", "children": [
        {"key": "20_1_1", "title": "Sub-item 2.1.1"},
        {"key": "20_1_2", "title": "Sub-item 2.1.2"}
    ]},
    {"key": "20_2", "title": "Sub-item 2.2", "children": [
        {"key": "20_2_1", "title": "Sub-item 2.2.1"},
        {"key": "20_2_2", "title": "Sub-item 2.2.2"}
    ]}
]},
{"key": "30", "title": "Lazy folder", "folder": true, "lazy": true },
{"key": "31", "title": "Lazy folder 2", "folder": true, "lazy": true },
{"key": "32", "title": "Lazy folder 3", "folder": true, "lazy": true }
]
```

Which, according to jsonlint.com, is valid json data.

But if I run this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a6e3/

Which contains this code:

```
$.getJSON( "http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/ajax-tree-plain.json", function() {
alert( "success" );
}).fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})
```

It returns an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy: code on `http://jsfiddle.net` (or `http://fiddle.jshell.net`) is not allowed to access resources from `http://wwwendt.de` -- unless the JSON file were served with the appropriate CORS headers to allow access.

Comment: When look at the chrome debugger I see error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: The downvote indicates that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I admit to not using the debugger, I don't have great experience in that and should try to educate myself in it's use. But, I did validate the json, created a simple jsfiddle to eliminate it wasn't anything at my end and did look at previous similar question on Stackoverflow. I also accidentally had the incorrect C# tag for all of 90 seconds on the question. I think some users forget being new at technology, it may have a simple answer to you, but that's not what the downvote is for.

Comment: I think you made a good effort to figure things out as well so that's why I upvoted you to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your problem is due to not having a required header:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

From this link:

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
>   headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
>   permitted to read that information using a web browser.

You need to have your server send this header down to the browser. Without the header you will not be able to make requests outside of the domain the page came from.